# Software to detect hardware bottlenecks?

Tags: performance, benchmarking

Is there software available that I can run on my system to detect possible hardware bottlenecks (CPU, RAM, Graphics, …)?

p/s : I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Windows those tools are called the Performance Monitor and Resource Monitor.  For Linux, top/htop can give you a lot of good info.  However, these tools will not draw conclusions for you.  You need to look at several things
- CPU use and processor queue length
- Hard Page faults (page faults that need to be read from swapfile/disk
- disk queue length

Queue lengths should not be sustained above 2 for nay resource (Multiply that by #cores for CPU)

Small numbers of page faults are OK.

Comment: In top of those two there are the SysInternals tools, specifically in this case: Diskmon, ProcessExplorer, ProcessMonitor and VMMap.